# Passing Data to other component after fetching from server and load other component with that data

Tags: reactjs

How can I pass data to another component (not related as parent child) after fetching from server and load other component with that data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Gaurav! This question is very broad. If you can't pass data down from a parent to a child, you can use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or a state management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/).

Comment: I dont want to use Redux or any other third party library.

Comment: You should find component what will be parent of both your components and set your fetch data in state of this component. And then give it to your target component as props

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've seen you need it to pass an object from `login` to `dashboard`, after user logs successfully and the server returns a response.

What are you using for authentication? 
Have you tried using `jwt` https://jwt.io/ ?

What you can do with it, is that the backend will send you a token and after you get it, you just save it in localStorage using

```
localStorage.setItem('my-token', tokenFromBackEnd);
```

Then you can use `jwt-decode` library to decode the token and get the full object
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode

and you can get it everywhere as an object by just writing this:

```
var decoded = jwt_decode(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must store your server requests in the Main component. It must be the parent for all other components. In this way, you can retrieve the data of any component below using props.

Comment: I have a login page which on successful login sends a User Object from the backend. I have to pass the object to another page called Dashboard and display some fields on it. How do I pass the User object from login.js to dashboard.js
My top component is App.js and other component are its children.

Comment: Save the user object and pass it through the hierarchy.